# What Markdown tags are previewed by Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, markdown

Dropbox [supports preview of Markdown](https://www.dropbox.com/help/6), but [not all tags](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tnd9vnyy7o92jp/dropbox-markdown-test.md). I have inferred that it supports most, perhaps all, of the Markdown-specific syntax, but not HTML tags. However, that level of "documentation" is rather shallow.

Is there any documentation available?

Comment: In addition to your test document, inline code, code blocks, quoted blocks and nested lists are also supported. But, as you suggest, not HTML tags (tried `del`, `s` and `sup` as well - which are the ones I tend to use with md).

Comment: Thanks @w3dk, I added your HTML use cases to the test doc.

Comment: Here’s a [list of existing extensions](https://github.com/jgm/CommonMark/wiki/Deployed-Extensions) (some conflicting), but it seems you’re not even testing all standard Markdown/Commonmark features yet. [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/demos.html) has some demo files you could try, too, or use an existing [cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet).

Comment: Hi @Crissov, if there's interest, I can try to make the test more complete. Perhaps I can just use the cheatsheet you suggested – thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get list of keyboards shortcuts (including Markdown tags) from Paper doc itself (as [help article](https://help.dropbox.com/view-edit/formatting) mentions):

> For a full list of keyboard shortcuts, click the keyboard shortcuts button (it looks like a keyboard) at the bottom-right of your Paper doc.

Scroll down opened panel to Markdown formatting section to see list of supported tags.

### Markdown formatting options available in Dropbox Paper

See table below (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4643i.png).

| Paper tag name | Paper tag format |
| --- | --- |
| Large header | `#` <kbd>Space</kbd> |
| Medium header | `##` <kbd>Space</kbd> |
| Small header | `###` <kbd>Space</kbd> |
| Numbered list | `1.` <kbd>Space</kbd> |
| Bulleted list | `*` <kbd>Space</kbd> |
| Task list | `[]` <kbd>Space</kbd> |
| Blockquote | `>` <kbd>Space</kbd> |
| Italic | `_Italic_` |
| Bold | `**Bold**` |
| Strikethrough | `~Strikethrough~` |
| Code block | ```` ``` ```` |
| Code | `` `code` `` |
| Divider | `---` |
| LaTeX | `$$\LaTeX$$` |

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the official documentation on formatting options available in Dropbox: [Formatting a Dropbox Paper doc](https://www.dropbox.com/help/paper/formatting) 
It also contains the available markdown tags supported by Dropbox Paper doc.

Answer (score -2):

There is some documentation here: https://rick.cogley.info/post/display-markdown-from-dropbox-with-mdwiki/